# Website Latency Oscillates With a Period Of 3 Minutes Between 40 -> 200 ms

Tags: docker, kubernetes, latency, google-kubernetes-engine, caddy

I host a static web page with [Caddy Server](https://caddyserver.com/) on [Google's managed Kubernetes service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/). I monitor this site with [Google Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/).

I deploy my code via a Helm chart. [See the source code here (permalink)](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/NoahHuppert.com/tree/c692886d32aa42b9eec4e3821e2b756d6429732c/deploy/noahhuppert-com).

I have noticed that the latency will oscillate between about 40 ms and 200 ms every 3 minutes. Almost like clockwork.

As far as I can tell there isn't an obvious correlation between CPU usage and the latency period.

Here is a histogram of CPU usage and latency:

[image]

What could be causing this oddly repetitive pattern?

Comment: Its impossible to point out the issue with no further details. But most probably that's your app.

Comment: @suren Are there any sort of details you would recommend providing to help debug this issue?

Comment: I would check all the internal links of the app, to be sure everything is being loaded locally. Are there databases?

Comment: All static pages. No Db. I'm wondering if it is some control loop of Kubernete's that is eating CPU?

Comment: We need to know more about how your pod is deployed (deployment YAML) as well as which service is being used to expose the application (service YAML and if you are using an Ingress, that YAML as well)

You can also run similar test by queurying the pod directly from within the cluster (use kubectl attach to connect to another pod) to see if the latency varies